# list-style-position does not work when list-marker is pseudo-element. Why?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I wanted to create colored list-markers for `<ul>` and I did it, but in all lists now the `list-style-position` attribute does not works.

Here is the code:

```css
ul.FirmStyle {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.FirmStyle li:before {
  color: orange;
  content: "▪";
  list-style-position: outside;
  /* !!!!!! */
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="FirmStyle">
  <li>A lot of texttttttttttttttttt-t-t-t-tttttttt-tt-tt-tt-ttttt-t-tttttt-t-tttt-tttt</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

Why?

Comment: Because it's not a list item bullet ...it's a different element entirely. Why should it act the same?

Comment: The easiest way to color your `list-style-item` is to color your entire UL and wrap your content inside another tag with the regular color.

Comment: Do you mean that item-bullet, if it's "none" is not invisible, it is not exists? And it means that my pseudo-marker is a simple text.

Comment: Yep, that's it precisely. See Harry's answer.

Comment: somethinghere, I know that way, but I think it is not good, because i will be musted to place <span> each time :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [W3C Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-lists-3), the `list-style-position` property controls the positioning of the marker pseudo element in the list item.

> [***list-style-position***](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-lists-3/#list-style-position-property)
>
> This property helps control the position of the ::marker pseudo-element in the list item.
>
> Note: Note that a marker is only generated if the used value of the content property for the ::marker pseudo-element is not none.

This marker is generated only when the contents of it is none but once you set `list-style-type` to `none` the contents of the marker is defaulted to none. Since no marker is created there is nothing to position.

> [***list-style-type***](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-lists-3/#marker-content)
>
> **none**
>
> The list item’s marker’s ***default contents are none***.

<sup>(emphasis is mine)</sup>

You'd have to position the `:before` pseudo-element manually using the `position` attributes (or) by adjusting the left and right margins accordingly. The below snippet has samples on how to achieve it using margins or positioning (and also an output with `list-style-position` for comparison).

```css
ul.FirmStyle{
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.FirmStyle li:before{
  color: orange; 
  content: "▪";
}
ul.FirmStyle.with-margin li:before{
  margin: 0px 12px 0px -16px;
}
ul.FirmStyle.with-position li:before{
  position: relative;
  left: -16px;
}
ul.FirmStyle2{
  list-style-position: outside;
}
```

```html
<ul class="FirmStyle with-margin">
  <li>A lot of texttttttttttttttttt-t-t-t-tttttttt-tt-tt-tt-ttttt-t-tttttt-t-tttt-tttt</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ul>
<ul class="FirmStyle2">
  <li>A lot of texttttttttttttttttt-t-t-t-tttttttt-tt-tt-tt-ttttt-t-tttttt-t-tttt-tttt</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ul>
<ul class="FirmStyle with-position">
  <li>A lot of texttttttttttttttttt-t-t-t-tttttttt-tt-tt-tt-ttttt-t-tttttt-t-tttt-tttt</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is that approach is safe, if i want to change the font size?

Comment: @YesMan: You're welcome. The approach is reasonably safe but if you want it to behave like `list-style-position` when `font-size` changes then it would be better to use `em` or `rem` for the margins (like `margin: 0px 0.75em 0px -1em;`).

Answer (score 2):

Bite late, but I just had the same problem!

Do the following to your pseudo element:

```
ul.FirmStyle li:before {
  color: orange;
  content: "▪";
  margin-left: -25px;  /* this is to move the icon left */
  padding-right: 10px; /* to keep some space between icon and text */
}
```

you dont need the  `list-style-position: outside;`