# list-style-position: outside not working HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why `list-style-position: outside` is not working. I have the important tag going and tried it in all my css classes, but it still will not catch.

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: outside !important;
}

ol.line {
  list-style-position: outside !important;
}

ol li:before {
  content: '✓';
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ol style="list-style-position: outside !important;">
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean</li>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. </li>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. </li>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. </li>
</ol>
```

([*codepen*](https://codepen.io/aoave-the-styleful/pen/mvRaVy))

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're using `list-style-type: none;`
Remove this to use the `list-style-type` property. If you don't want numbers (`orderd list`), consider using `<ul>` and change the bullet points with psuedo elements

Answer (score 1):

check this link

[list-style-position does not work when list-marker is pseudo-element. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790393/list-style-position-does-not-work-when-list-marker-is-pseudo-element-why)

or try this.

```css
ol {
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside !important;
  }

ol li { padding-left:30px;position:relative;}

ol li:before {
    display:block;
    content: '✓';
    font-size: 30px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    top:0;
  }
```

```html
<ol style="list-style-position: outside !important;">
    <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,      consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean </li>
    
    <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. </li>
    
   <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. </li>
  
   <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. </li>
                  
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use list-style-type on your li instead of a content on li::before.

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: outside !important;
}

ol.line {
  list-style-position: outside !important;
}

li {
    list-style-type: "\1F44D";
}
```

```html
<ol style="list-style-position: outside !important;">
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean</li>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. </li>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. </li>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a `list-style-position` beacuse the `list-style` is not defined. But if you want your checks before each li, you can change the position of your `li:before` like this:

(Sory for my english)

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol li {
  position: relative;
}
ol li:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '✓';
  left: -23px;
  top: -8px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean</li>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. </li>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. </li>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Don't just spit out code. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Yes i go try explain better